# grpc_cli for gRPC-Web

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

Is there any CLI to call gRPC-Web service like grpc_cli?

I'd like to test our gRPC-Web service running on AWS.  I cannot use grpc_cli because the gRPC service is in a private subnet and not accessible (I cannot put the service behind our ELB, which does not support Http/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at **Chrome Browser extension to aid gRPC-Web development**

https://github.com/SafetyCulture/grpc-web-devtools

Hope this help